# Importing data into SQL Server with a SSIS package but code page causes problems

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to transfer some data from one SQL Server to another, so that I can re-engineer a data model I believe to be problematical.
I am using SSMS and the Tasks > Export > SSIS packages to extract flatfiles, and then import them again on the other server.

I get this message

> Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page

- Source: Latin1_General_CI_AS / SQL Server 2016 (v13.0)
- Target: Latin1_General_CI_AS / SQL Server 2019 (v15.0)

Both export and import use the same codepage... `1252 (ANSI - Latin I)`

The DTX file has the element `DTS:CodePage="1252"`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like a collation mismatch. What are the collations of - both - the source and target columns?

Comment: Had to lookup what collation is. Both databases are MS-SQL Server. 
Source: Latin1_General_CI_AS / Target: Latin1_General_CI_AS and the version are Source is ver 13.0   / Target is ver 15.0

Comment: What version of SSMS are you using?

Comment: Version 18.12.1  And also tried 19.3

Comment: Do your tables have correct datalength of parameters? It's talking about truncation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a 2 step process: Export Data to Flat File, and Import Data from Flat File.

The Export to Flat File, created via the wizard, will create a flat file that has the correct lengths because it will use the metadata stores in SQL Server to specify said data.

The Import from Flat File, also created via the wizard, does *not* know anything about the original table specifications. It is going to make a default guess that everything in a flat file is 50 characters unless you tell it otherwise.

On the Advanced tab, this will list the columns and selecting any single column will allow you to modify the data type. I "know" Col1 should be varchar(100) so I'd change 50 to 100. Repeat this for all your columns

[image]

The other option is to let SSIS "guess." This can be a mixed bag because it's going to look at N rows (200 as a default)

[image]

Were it me, I would increase that to something larger, say 1000, maybe 10000 rows.

- Uncheck Smallest Integer
- Uncheck Smallest Real
- Check Pad String columns and pick say 10%

When I have the data in the database, then I can profile it and make determinations like "this integer fits into a tinyint domain." If I let the SSIS analyzer make that determination, row 1001 or 10001 will have an value that inevitably blows up the small sizing assumption.

And since you're using the wizard, you have to restart the whole click path of Tasks, Import Data, find the file, etc etc. This will allow you to get through the "hard" part of disk into database with the least probable failure path

Comment: This is the explanation I was looking for ... I never thought about the default interpretation of flat file data.